# Show that $f(b)=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{f^{(r)}(a)}{r!}(b-a)^r + \frac1{n!} \int_a^bf^{(n+1)}(t)(b-t)^ndt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f^{(n+1)}$ be integrable on [a,b].  Show that $$f(b)=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{f^{(r)}(a)}{r!}(b-a)^r + \frac1{n!} \int_a^bf^{(n+1)}(t)(b-t)^n \ dt$$

From the form it looks like I'll need to use integration by parts and inductive methods, but I'm having a hard time finding a starting point.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is the standard Taylor series for $f(x+h)$ with $x=a$ and $h = b-a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to look at it  : both 
$$f(x) - \sum_{r=0}^n \frac{f^{(r)}(a)}{r!}(x-a)^r$$ 
and
$$\frac{1}{n!} \int_a^{x} f^{(n+1)}(t) (x-t)^n dt$$

are the (unique) solution of the differential equation of order $n+1$ 
$$y^{(n+1)} = f^{(n+1)} \\
y(a) = y'(a) = \ldots = y^{(n)}(a) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use induction. For the $n\to n+1$ part,
integrate by parts using
$$
\frac{(b-t)^n}{n!} \to -
\frac{(b-t)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
\\
f^n \to f^{n+1}
$$

The initialization of the induction is just the fundamental theorem of integral calculus.